# ASP.NET Crystal Reports image field not showing

Tags: asp.net, image, crystal-reports

I am using VS-2008 for asp.net web application. However, I have developed my reports in VS 2005. ( I am reusing some reports that were developed in other project).

The reports work fine except the image field is not displayed. The image field is a 'VARBINARY(MAX)' field in database. Note that when I export my Crystal Report to .pdf the images shows up in the .pdf file.

(* I am able to see an image url in 'Firebug' but getting message 'Load Image failed')

I am using a 'TypedDataset' as DataSource for the Crystal Report.

I fetch the data from database and do a 'DataSet.WriteXML(filename,WriteMode.WriteSchema)'

Here is the code:-

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim rgx As Regex = New Regex("[^a-zA-Z0-9 -]")
    strComp = rgx.Replace(strComp, "")
    strFile = "tempXML" + strComp + ".xml"
    Dim dsTemp As New DataSet
    dsTemp.Clear()
    dsTemp.Tables.Clear()
    Dim rptengine As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
    rptengine.Load(Session("rptname"))
    sdate = CType(Session("sdate"), Date)
    edate = CType(Session("edate"), Date)
    rptHeading = Session("rptHead")

    If IO.File.Exists(Server.MapPath("~/" + strFile)) Then
        dsTemp.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/" + strFile), XmlReadMode.ReadSchema)
        'IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/" + strFile))
        Try
            If Session("rptname").ToString.Substring(Session("rptname").ToString.LastIndexOf("\") + 1) _
                = "Rptemp.rpt" Then
                Dim dsReport As New DDL.dsEmpList
                dsReport.Tables("dtEmpList").Merge(dsTemp.Tables(0))
                rptengine.SetDataSource(dsReport.Tables(0))
            ElseIf Session("rptname").ToString.Substring(Session("rptname").ToString.LastIndexOf("\") + 1) _
                = "rptDailyAttendance.rpt" Then
                Dim dsReport As New DDL.dsDailyReoprt
                dsReport.Tables("dtDailyReport").Merge(dsTemp.Tables(0))
                rptengine.SetDataSource(dsReport.Tables(0))
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            ShowMsg1("Exception : " & ex.Message)
        End Try


        '**********************assigning CR-ParameterFields*****************************
        Dim crParameterFieldDefinitions As ParameterFieldDefinitions
        Dim crParameterFieldDefinition As ParameterFieldDefinition
        Dim crParameterValues As ParameterValues
        Dim crParameterDiscreteValue As ParameterDiscreteValue
        Dim parameterToDefine As Boolean = False

        crParameterFieldDefinitions = rptengine.DataDefinition.ParameterFields

        For Each crParameterFieldDefinition In crParameterFieldDefinitions
            crParameterDiscreteValue = New ParameterDiscreteValue
            crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues
            Select Case crParameterFieldDefinition.Name
                Case "sdate"
                    parameterToDefine = True
                    crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = sdate
                Case "edate"
                    parameterToDefine = True
                    crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = edate
                Case "heading"
                    parameterToDefine = True
                    crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = rptHeading
                Case Else
                    parameterToDefine = False
            End Select

            If parameterToDefine Then
                Try
                    crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue)
                    crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)
                Catch ex As Exception
                    objdata.writelog(ex.Message, "frmRptEngine", "frmRptEngine_Load", Server.MapPath("~/Reports"))
                    ShowMsg1("Error in report generation.")
                    Exit Sub
                End Try
            End If
        Next

        rptViewer.ReportSource = Nothing
        rptViewer.ReportSource = rptengine
        rptViewer.Enabled = True
        rptViewer.DataBind()
    Else
        ShowMsg1("Invalid attempt.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Html for the Image field from Firebug is :- <div class="ad7947c08a-5302-4857-9061-8656ab9f1e09-1" style="top: 3px; left: 351px; width: 75px; height: 76px;">
<img height="76px" border="0" width="75px" alt="Image" src="/taweb/CrystalImageHandler.aspx?dynamicimage=cr_tmp_image_c0ad7cce-209d-47c0-b11e-ca4a2cf9d21e.png">
</div>

Answer (score 2):

For those of us running migrated projects from .Net 4.0 or lower to 4.5+  I have made an observation. It seems if your page that contains the viewer is in a subdirectory then the image urls are being generated relative to that page and not to the root of the web application. E.g if your page is /gl/accounts.aspx then the image may be /gl/crystalimagehandler.aspx etc
A quick way to fix this is to change your handler mapping to a wildcard ending in crystalimagehandler.aspx or put the following code in Global.asax

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var p = Request.Path.ToLower().Trim();
            if (p.EndsWith("/crystalimagehandler.aspx") && p!= "/crystalimagehandler.aspx")
            {
                var fullPath=Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower();
                var index = fullPath.IndexOf("/crystalimagehandler.aspx");
                Response.Redirect(fullPath.Substring(index));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Good information but I got past this issue, but I will +1 your answer. Next time I will give your solution a try.